# The slide is not created with the correct page size, specified in the body request

Tags: google-slides-api

I'm using the Google Slides API, I used the page size parameter, when I created a new presentation, but is ignored ? How I can do that ? How I can create a new presentation with a custom page size ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`presentations.create`](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/create) where the request body will look like this:

```
{
  "presentationId": string,
  "pageSize": {
      "width": {
           "magnitude": number,
           "unit": enum(Unit)
       },
      "height": {
           "magnitude": number,
           "unit": enum(Unit)
     }
  },
  "slides": [
    {
      object(Page)
    }
  ],
  "title": string,
  "masters": [
    {
      object(Page)
    }
  ],
  "layouts": [
    {
      object(Page)
    }
  ],
  "locale": string,
  "revisionId": string,
  "notesMaster": {
    object(Page)
  }
}
```

You can also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658618/cannot-create-a-presentation-with-pagesize-on-google-slides-api) for same related issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work either. The pageSize field is just ignored.The link to the SO post seems to be the only workaround.