# Is there a known way to update the page setup size In the Google Slides API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I've been poking around in the Google Slides API documentation. I can only find a way to update the element sizes. What I want to do is update the page setup size to widescreen 16:10.

I looked at this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/presentations) and [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/moving-elements) but this just references page elements, not the slide its self. Is there any preferred or suggested way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are links to the Google Apps Script Slides Service documentation (known as a **built-in** service). It gives you access to some features of the Google Slides API but not all. What you need is the [advanced slides service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides), which is a direct analog of the [Google Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/). To use them effectively read the [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) guide for more information.

You can set the page size of a presentation ***when its created*** using the Advanced Service ([see reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/create)). However your presentation may be letter-boxed (top and bottom padded with black boxes) if your presentations have a high width-to-height ratio.

Comment: What happens if the slide has already been created and you only want to update it?

Comment: I see! It returns a new slide. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you think you could show me an example? I'm still not able to update the sizes of every presentation I have. I've tried looping over every ID Slides.Presentations.create(REQUEST, slidesId[i]); but this does nothing.

Comment: Based on what I've seen in the documentation you can only set the dimensions of a presentation when its created. There doesn't seem to be a way to change/update the dimensions of a pre-existing presentation.

Comment: You actually cannot set the size using that create API. "If a presentationId is provided, it is used as the ID of the new presentation. Otherwise, a new ID is generated. Other fields in the request, including any provided content, are ignored." It actually ignores the `size` field.

Comment: see my answer to a similar question, which provides a work around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58528167/change-page-size-in-google-slide-with-gas/77845951#77845951

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround for that issue. Create a template presentation, modify it and then copy it using Google Drive API. See more details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678345/2987759

Comment: This is a link to the Slides API bug. If more people star it, maybe it will get fixed instead of requiring workaround: issuetracker.google.com/issues/74602138 – d35348w May 26 at 16:05