# How can I modify a Google Slides presentation's aspect ratio through the Slides API?

Tags: python, google-api, google-slides-api, google-slides

I am trying to use the [Google Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/) for Python to allow users to add presentations to a project.
The presentations must fit a 4:3 aspect ratio due to display limitations. How can I verify a presentation is in this format?

```py
#authentication...
service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=creds)
presentation = service.presentations().get(
    presentationId=PRESENTATION_ID).execute()

presentation.get(...)  #what goes here?
```

Answer (score -1):

Please be noted that the [Slides API might refactor your values](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/transform#the_slides_api_might_refactor_your_values):

> When you create a page element, you can specify a size and transform
>   that provide a certain visual result. However, the API may replace
>   your provided values with other ones that yield the same visual
>   appearance. In general, if you write a size using the API, you are not
>   guaranteed to be returned the same size. However, you should get the
>   same results if you take the transform into account.

However, there's another solution wherein you can use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides#read_page_element_object_ids) to modify the page size of your Slides. You can check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008555/is-there-a-known-way-to-update-the-page-setup-size-in-the-google-slides-api) for more details.