# Change page size in google slide with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting

I need help, please.

I have a google slide and I need to set the page size to 19.05 width and 27.51 height with scripts.
I know I have to use the batchUpdate method, but I have no idea how to run it... Any examples?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for changing the page size of the Slides using [Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest) and [Slides Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides). Even when new Slides is created using Slides API, although there is the parameter of `pageSize` in the request body, this parameter doesn't work. So as the current answer, unfortunately, the page size of Slides cannot be changed. But Slides API and Slides Service are growing now. So this might be modified in the future.

Comment: I'm crying right now, but thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that your issue cannot be resolved soon.

Comment: Submitted https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113  - probably not a good explanation as I am a novice. Please improve

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191809064

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible, programatically! Please raise it as a missing feature here - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113

Answer (score 0):

With Google App Script you *cannot*:

- change the format of a Presentation
- change the format of a Slide
- create a Presentation at the format you specify

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54009557/798502) says it should be possible to create a Presentation at a given size, using the Advanced Service, [but this is actually not possible](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/slides/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Slides_1_1v1_1_1PresentationsResource_1_1CreateRequest.html).

A work around is:

1. create manually an empty Google Slide Presentation (called it "A") at the size you prefer.
2. Copy this template to a new document B
3. Insert the slide of interest in B. The slide will get resized to the size you had specified for A.
4. Keep doc A for similar, future use.

This isn't useful for every situation, in particular when you have constantly varying slide sizes to deal with. But it is useful for, say, conversions between typical file formats such as 16:9 to 4:3.